# Can a perfect (diffraction limited but monochromatic) single lens microscope exist?

Tags: optics

Light is refracted as it enters a lens, travels some distance, and is again refracted when it exits the other surface. It seems to me that this provides enough information to solve for the perfect microscope objective lens, which takes a beam of parallel rays and focuses them with enough magnification to function as a microscope, and without any spherical aberration.

All standard optical equipment (microscopes, telescope and binocular eyepieces) however combine many spherical lenses together in a symmetric design so that the aberrations oppose each other and mostly cancel out.

If we ignore chromatic aberration, is a single lens design possible? Would the depth of field be limited by this type of design? What makes complicated multiple lens designs so attractive?